# Lion Server: Send remote lock from outside LAN

Tags: server.app, profile-manager

I've setup the profile manager and locking a laptop works great while on the same LAN as the Lion server but if I'm outside the office it will never get the remote lock request. The Lion server is behind a NAT. Do I need to forward ports to the lion server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to either [forward these ports](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5302) to your Lion server, or put the Lion server in your firewall's DMZ. You will also need to make sure that the DNS name of your Lion server is resolvable to devices outside of your network.

The Apple Push Notification service used by Profile Manager will tell your device "Check in with this server", but your server needs to be resolvable and accessible for your device to actually check in and get the command that you've set for it in Profile Manager. That's why the lock command is working while your laptop is on the same LAN as the server.

Comment: That's the way.

Comment: do you know what ports need to be opened?

Comment: `2195, 2196 - TCP - Used by Profile Manager to send push notifications`

`5223 - TCP - Used to maintain a persistent connection to APNs and receive push notifications`

`80/443 - TCP - Provides access to the web interface for Profile Manager admin`

`1640 - TCP - Enrollment access to the Certificate Authority`